# Calling StartActivityForResult() in Activity for multiple times for scanner

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have two button in my activity to scan. But how can i differentiate between each one in on activityForResult? I know I should be using StartActivityforResult() and pass a number for each scan but I couldn't figure out how to do it with integrator.

```
  ibBinScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scan();
            }
        });

  ibNumberScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scan();
            }
        });

    public void scanNow() {
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(InboundActivity.this);
        integrator.setCaptureActivity(Portait.class);
        integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
        integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
        integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
        integrator.setPrompt("Scan Barcode");
        integrator.initiateScan();
    }


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (result != null) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {}
            if (requestCode == 2) {}

        } else super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use :

```
integrator.setRequestCode(REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: There's no method called setRequestCode in IntentIntegrator class. I looked at it too the RequestCode is also a final.

Comment: https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/13440ad8751dcaba4177fa50dfee639dac52a53d/zxing-android-embedded/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java#L127  :  this class have setRequestCode() method

Answer (score 0):

`IntentIntegrator` fro zxing does have a request code setter for Intent. Try this way :-

```
public static final int REQ_CODE1=23;
public static final int REQ_CODE2=25;

public void scanNow(int requestCode) {
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(InboundActivity.this);
    integrator.setCaptureActivity(Portait.class);
    integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
    integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
    integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setPrompt("Scan Barcode");
    integrator.setRequestCode(requestCode)
    integrator.initiateScan();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if((requestCode==REQ_CODE1 || requestCode==REQ_CODE2) && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==REQ_CODE1){

        }else(requestCode==REQ_CODE2){

        }
    }else{

    }
}
```

Comment: There's no setRequest Method in IntentIntegrator Class. also they have the requestCode as a final.

Comment: There is one [See this version](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) .. What dependency are you using ?

Comment: I have these two  
   implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'

Comment: I tried using the new version. I got Sync issue ERROR: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors. Do you know why that might happened?

Comment: Update dependency for `com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded` from the link above . It will work ..

Comment: `Manifest merger failed with multiple errors` .. You need to migrate to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)..  But first look `dm77/barcodescanner` support androidX or not(its an old Lib not updated)..Why you need two libraries anyway ??

Comment: Yeah I removed dm77/barcodescanner. And i'm using androidX already

Comment: I'm using implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

Comment: I added     <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.zxing.client.android" /> in Manifest and now it's working! Thanks. If you could update your answer for others

Comment: I got another error after running the application. Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): void com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeCallback.possibleResultPoints(java.util.List)